# Differential Equation monotone solution

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

I have this functional, $W\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d), u \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$
$$I_\varepsilon[u]:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}W(u)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}||\nabla u||^2dx$$
I derived the Euler-Lagrange eqations which is
$$-\varepsilon \Delta u+W'(u)=0$$
Now we have this boundary problem with $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

$$-\varepsilon u''+W'(u)=0; \ u(\pm \infty)=\pm 1$$
With W having the following properties:

- $W\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$
- $W(u)>0  \ \forall u  \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$
- $W(\pm 1)=W'(\pm 1)=0$

Show that every solution $u_\varepsilon$ is monotone and $u_\varepsilon(x)\in ]-1,1[$

I tried arguing with the functional or taking the derivative to get $u'$ but it didnt work like I expected.

Comment: What do you mean by monotone in $\mathbb R^d$? At one point you write $u’’$. Should $d=1$?

Comment: In the boundary problem u is in $\mathbb{R}$. Thank you I will edit it and make it clear.

Comment: Any conditions on $\varepsilon$? Is it positive?